# Understanding Network Delivery Methods?

Tags: networking, udp, game-development, multiplayer

I'm currently learning how to create a custom UDP protocol to act like TCP for faster transfer of data in a fast-paced multiplayer game.

I've got the basics down but don't understand when each of the delivery methods and when they should be used.

They are:

- Unreliable (UDP) - Realtime movement, fast-paced actions
- ReliableOrdered (TCP) - non-realtime things, chat messages, score updates
- UnreliableSequenced - Voice/Video over IP
- ReliableUnordered - Independent status updates, collecting items, etc
- ReliableSequenced - Non-Realtime Video Streaming

I understand the first two. Unreliable is just plain UDP and ReliableOrdered is TCP, however, when should these be used.

I'm assuming ReliableOrdered would be for something like Game chat and Unreliable would be for movement/combat but what about the other 3?

I enjoy learning networking as it's a huge challenge and I hope I can find an answer for this?

Thank you

Comment: *"...  and when they should be used ..."* - why do you think they should be used at all in your project? If you have a specific use case (game) then design or choose the protocol so that it fits the use case and not design a overly flexible protocol and find use cases for it. That's even worse than an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) because that's basically inventing a solution and then searching for a matching problem. And, there is not much known about your use case except "game", so how can we know what kind of problems you need to solve there.

Comment: You should study [SCTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4960) that can do just about all of that.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm mainly talking about general cases (ReliableOrdered would be for chat) and theory. Like when one would be used over the other. I'm learning game development in college but I'm not making an actual game atm.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Cyberboy1551: *UnreliableSequenced* is relevant for things like Voice/Video over IP, where it is ok to loose packets but it is necessary that the sequence is known to align with the timing and that the packets arrive in time. *ReliableSequenced* is similar but for codecs where loss of data is not acceptable but latency is not that relevant - like non-realtime video streaming. *ReliableUnordered* could be used for independent status updates, like collecting items where at the end only the kind of items is relevant but not the order of collection.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. I'll update my original post with the ones I've found answers for. Let me know if it's incorrect in anyway. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Typically speaking, you will only ever use TCP and UDP protocols in games, unless you including voice chat which you've already covered.

UDP covers things which are likely to change constantly and don't particularly care if there is a little margin for error. They are also usually simulated on clients in between time, eg a players location on a map as they move around. You can store a direction but do regular updates to make sure clients don't see something totally different.

TCP is usually for everything else, especially if it involves user input or impact on controls. All of those infrequent or important updates.

Now with that being said, most game engines will pack multiple variable updates into a single packet which is sent every 0.2s or so, not every frame. This is to prevent network flooding, and depending on the game engine, is usually referred to as a network update, which is conditionally skipped during the normal game loop.

In general, the more you can push to UDP the better, due to the reduced network impact, but it's usually not possible to do, or rather not practical.